# How can I debug Fastlane file in VSCode with "VSCode rdbg Ruby Debugger" or similar?

Tags: ruby, visual-studio-code, debugging, fastlane

I'm trying to debug my custom lane Fastlane code within VSCode, but it cannot find Fastlane source code. What may be a minimal launch.json snippet and what other setup is necessary?

So far I tried the following launch.json config:

```js
...
    {
      "type": "rdbg",
      "name": "Debug Fastlane",
      "request": "launch",
      "script": "/opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/bin/fastlane",
      "args": ["my_lane"]
    },
...
```

The Fastlane snippet:

```rb
platform :ios do
  desc "My lane"
  lane :my_lane do |options|
    require 'debug'
    binding.break
...
```

I can debug from command line:

```bash
rdbg -c -- bundle exec fastlane my_lane
```

However, if I try to debug from VSCode, it cannot find Fastlane file location:

```
Could not load source 'Fastfile': not found....
```

Expectedly without source code breakpoints and binding.break don't work as expected.